# Best approach to handle database transactions and business logic

Tags: database, transactions, logic

I wonder if it is right to handle the transactions of the database as follows:

```
    **locate database service**
         **open connection**
              **begin transaction**
                  get objects from relational database
                  call business logic
              **commit transaction**
         **close connection**
    **release**
```

The code in asterisks its going to be injected via IoC**

While thus the business logic is not affected by data access code, asked whether the implementation is correct and what possible consequences it brings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't want to keep transaction open while dealing with business logic. Your application may perform lengthy computations, sending data over network, calling remote services, etc. Having database transaction open during this process can and will cause many problems; some of them are deadlocks, running out of RDMS connection pool, lock escalation, lost updates, etc.

In general, Repository module is responsible for loading/persisting objects, including transaction management. Business logic doesn't have to worry about transactions, all it needs to know is how to call the right method of Repository. Also, don't forget that storing data may fail due to a number of reasons, so make sure you handle it properly. For example,

1.Read objects from external storage (transaction management, if any, is hidden inside Repository)
2.Manipulate objects according to business logic
3.Store result of manipulation (assuming your storage is RDMS that supports transaction, you begin transaction, save data, commit if success, rollback if error)

Comment: -1 Using a single database transaction to bound business logic is critical to ensuring database integrity. Without it, there are no guarantees that the changes you are validating or saving are remain valid between the time you check and the time you save.

Comment: @kgrittn: The are many different ways to ensure that saved data remain valid. Keeping transaction open for a long time is more dangerous.

Comment: I certainly don't advocate keeping transactions open while waiting for user input, but automated application of business logic normally is not on a time scale where this should be a problem. In particular, writing to the database with the results of applying business logic to what is read from the database (or triggered from writing related data to the database) must be done in the same transaction to prevent other readers from seeing an inconsistent database state.

Comment: @kgrittn: Using transaction by itself cannot guarantee business rules (unless it can be expressed on db level). If all parts of application don't use `serializable` isolation level(which is very expensive in terms of server resources), none of the problems related to lost updates are solved. It's quite common to make calls to remote (in many cases 3rd party) webservices using data stored in database. If transaction remains open during such a call, it's the first step toward disaster. Database state should not be inconsistent unless it's a serious bug in particular RDMS implementation.

Comment: Where in the question do you see any suggestion that the business logic involves reaching out to slow and/or unreliable resources?  Admittedly, when we have transactions which must do that, we have a timeout of a few seconds and if we hit the timeout we commit leaving the incomplete data flagged as being in an error state until the transaction can be retried later, but I don't see any suggestion of needing to deal with such issues in the question.

Comment: By the way, how expensive `SERIALIZABLE` transactions are depends on the implementation. I admit that old-fashioned Strict Two Phase Locking (S2PL) techniques can be prohibitively expensive. There are newer techniques which provide the same guarantees with (generally) much less overhead.

Comment: Regardless of implementation, `SERIALIZABLE` is the most expensive (and potentially most dangerous) isolation level. There are very few parts in almost any system that do in fact require it. Even in these case, it's almost always possible to find alternative solution. I do insist that with some rare exceptions, reading and writing within the same transaction is not required to implement business logic.

Comment: I was reading about Spring, in this framework a Dynamic proxy (also Transactional Proxy) are used to create a "safe" boudary around the business logic. In this case, what happens if the business logic execution takes more time than spected? A connection timeout?. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is sufficient overhead to locating a database service and opening a connection that you normally want to keep the connection open for re-use.  A connection pool can do this if it is inconvenient in the application.